# Triggering AJAX Validation is Causing Form to Duplicate

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm having a problem with a website project I've been working on.  I'll summarise here but this has already been documented on another forum (provided by a plugin provider) that goes into every detail:

https://toolset.com/forums/topic/post-edit-form-duplicating-body-contents-when-validation-is-triggered

Essentially, I'm using a suite of tools known as Toolset to build a highly customised system for managing classes within a WordPress website.  The problem I'm having is focused on a specific edit form that simply loads the data from the current custom post in the loop and allows the user to update most parts of the custom post.  This is all built-in functionality of Toolset and works perfectly fine, but I've added some custom validation (again, through built-in functionality of Toolset via a PHP hook) and although this works, generates the correct errors, and prevents the form submitting, if I use AJAX to submit the form so that the errors appear without the form reloading, then the form duplicates itself directly beneath the first one.

[image]

The modal that generates it is very standard and looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editTermModal-[wpv-post-id]" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editTermModalLabel-[wpv-post-id]" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editTermModalLabel-[wpv-post-id]">Edit Term</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        [cred_form form="edit-term-rebuild"]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been over everything I can think of, but nothing is making any difference to this behaviour.  Just for reference, here's what I've tried:

- Rebuilt the form, different ID,
- Tested each validation function one at a time,
- Rebuilt the modal code,
- Deactivated all plugins except Toolset Types, Blocks and Forms,
- Tried both the default theme, not my child theme, and 2021,

Here's the validation code, id 732 refers to the edit form in question.

```
<?php
/**
 * Functions that provide custom validation for Cred Forms (submit via AJAX to get them to run in modal)
 **/

toolset_snippet_security_check() or die( 'Direct access is not allowed' );

function my_validation($error_fields, $form_data)
{
  //Load list of field data comprised of field values and errors
  list( $fields, $errors ) = $error_fields;
  //uncomment this if you want to print the field values
  //print_r($fields);

  //** Validation for New Term form OR Edit Term form OR Edit Term Dates form **//
  if( $form_data['id'] == 446 || $form_data['id'] == 732 || $form_data['id'] == 1132 )
  {

    /* Validation - Check the End Date comes after the Start Date */
    if ( $fields['wpcf-term-start-date']['value']['datepicker'] > $fields['wpcf-term-end-date']['value']['datepicker'])
    {
      //End Date error message
      $errors['term-end-date'] = 'End Date must be greater than the Start Date';
    }

    /* Validation - Check the Start Date is in the same year as the Term Year selected */    
    //Set Term Year based on the form type
    //If New Term Form use form field
    if( $form_data['id'] == 446 ) {
      $year = $fields['wpcf-term-year']['value'];
      //If Edit Term form OR Edit Term Dates form pull the year from the post meta
    } elseif( $form_data['id'] == 732 || $form_data['id'] == 1132 ) {
      $year = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-term-year', true );
    }

    //Check the Start Date chosen is in the same year as the Term Year
    if( $year != date('Y', $fields['wpcf-term-start-date']['value']['datepicker']))
    {
      //Start Date year error message
      $errors['term-start-date'] = 'This Term must Start Date must be within the selected Term Year of ' . $year;
    }
    //Check the End Date is in the same year as the Term Year selected
    elseif($year != date('Y', $fields['wpcf-term-end-date']['value']['datepicker']))
    {
      //End Date year error message
      $errors['wpcf-term-end-date'] = 'This Term must end within the selected Term Year of ' . $year;
    }
  } 

  //** Validation for New Term form OR Edit Term form OR Edit Term Name form **//
  if( $form_data['id'] == 446 || $form_data['id'] == 732 || $form_data['id'] == 1131 )
  {

    /* Validation - Check if a Term with the same name has already been created */
    //Assemble name from form fields
    $current_term = $fields['wpcf-school-term']['value'] . " " . $fields['wpcf-term-year']['value'];

    //If one of the edit forms
    if( $form_data['id'] == 732 || $form_data['id'] == 1131 ) {

      //Get the stored Term Name
      $stored_term = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-school-term', true ) . " " . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-term-year', true );

      //If the stored name and entered name are different
      if( $current_term != $stored_term ) {
        //Check if the entered Term Name matches a Term Name that already exists
        $post_exists = post_exists( $current_term, null, null, 'academic-term', null);
      //If the stored and entered name are the same
      } else {
        //Set $post_exists to 0 to fail the existance check
        $post_exists = 0;
      }

    //If New Term form
    } else {

      //Check if the Term being created matches a Term name that already exists
      $post_exists = post_exists( $current_term, null, null, 'academic-term', null);

    }

    //If a Term with the same does exist
    if( $post_exists > 0 )
    {
      //Duplicate Term Name error message (doesn't matter if this is attributed to term or year as they both form the title, term is used as it's first)
      $errors['school-term'] = $fields['wpcf-school-term']['value'] . " " . $fields['wpcf-term-year']['value'] . ' already exists, so you cannot create another one.';
    }
  }

  //** Validation for New Term form OR Edit Term form OR Edit Term Token End Date form **//
  if( $form_data['id'] == 446 || $form_data['id'] == /*732*/2023 || $form_data['id'] == 1912 )
  {

    if( $form_data['id'] == 446 ) {
      $term_end_date = $fields['wpcf-term-end-date']['value']['datepicker'];
    } else {
      $term_end_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-term-end-date', true );
    }

    /* Validation - Check the Token End Date comes after the Term End Date */
    if ( $fields['wpcf-term-token-end-date']['value']['datepicker'] != NULL && $fields['wpcf-term-token-end-date']['value']['datepicker'] < $term_end_date )
    {
      //Token End Date error message
      $errors['term-token-end-date'] = 'Token End Date must be greater than or equal to the Term End Date of ' . date( 'd/m/Y', $term_end_date );
    }
  }

  //Return array of results
  return array( $fields, $errors );
}
add_filter('cred_form_validate','my_validation',10,2);
```

As I mentioned, I've tried working through this with their support, who are usually very good, but they haven't been much use this time.

It's definitely related to AJAX, but nothing I'm able to change seems to be affecting it.  There's no other custom JS running on this page and the same validation code is used on other forms on other pages without issue as well as the same modal layout being used for other edit forms in identical circumstances for other archives, again without issue.  Whatever this is, it's isolated to this specific form and location.

What can I try next?

### Update

Following @lothric's advice below, I've checked the Network monitor and as far as I understand this it seems to be working correctly, but rather than put the output in a comment, I'll add all the calls for the submission to admin-ajax.php here:

```
send                        @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
ajax                        @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
s.ajax.s.ajax               @   jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2
O.fn.ajaxSubmit             @   jquery.form.min.js?ver=4.3.0:1
self.onValidatedSubmitForm  @   frontend.js?ver=2.6.12:1076
d                           @   toolset-event-manager.min.js?ver=1.0:1
j                           @   toolset-event-manager.min.js?ver=1.0:1
(anonymous)                 @   validation.js?ver=4.1.8:323
dispatch                    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
v.handle                    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
```

The validation is there running right after submission and I've compared the calls being made to another form when the same validation is run and the calls are all the same.

Comment: Share code where you handle validations and AJAX?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I've added the validation code, but there's no direct interaction with AJAX, it's all done via the inbuilt functions and features of WordPress, Toolset and Bootstrap so I'm not sure if it's of any help.

Comment: Check the ajax response, maybe that duplicated form comes from there. Or maybe it's JavaScript problem - figure that out first.

Comment: @Lothric, could you offer any direction on how to go about that please?  JS / AJAX etc is really not my strong point at all.

Comment: @FeelContent, open Developer Tools in your browser, go to Network tab, make ajax request and you'll see it there in the list, open it and check the response, if it contains the form or not. If there's no form, I'd check JS that adds the error to your form.